# How to fetch TestNG Eclipse Test run status info from Console to use it when required?

Tags: selenium, testng

I am trying to use the TestNG Test run status information (i.e. the Passed Tests, Failed Tests, Skipped Tests).

Ex-  Want to use this

```
Sanity_Suite
=======================
Total tests run: 6,Passed:4, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
=========================================
```

I have written a method that sends test status information via sms to a recipient. Here is the ->[image: sendTestReportBySMS() method]

I have used ITestReporter, ITestResult, TestNG and other related contexts to get the correct test run status, I am using TestNG and ExtentReporter both and trying to fetch the information through anyway round possible. But I am getting mixed or incorrect results.

(BELOW IS THE SMS RECEIVED)

[image: sms_snapshot]

Is there any suggestions to get it done?

Answer (score 0):

I get that You are trying to send out sms with testresults.Could You please provide what is ITestResults object. Or to make it easier try with StringBuilder class, maybe it will ease up and fix Your issue:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Titlle\n");
sb.append("Passed: " + cntPass + "\n");
sb.append("Failed: " + cntFail + "\n");
sb.append("Description: " + description +"\n");
return sb.toString();
```

From the given code, its actually really hard to see full picture.

Comment: thanks for the suggest. I will do a check and will post back with the results on StringBuilder, and yes i am trying to stick some more code sample that can give a clarity on the Reporter objects.

Comment: Getting same results. I can see that the listener objects of both the reporting tools(TestNG and ExtentReport) are mapping Test run status in their own way. i.e. if for example Test Cases:5 , Passed 4 Failed:1 Skip:0  , then for TestNG listeners the data stored in them is Test Cases :5 Passed : 1 Failed: 2 Skipped:0

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking for. TestNG would be reporting the results in a proper way and that is what you should be relying up